# Думать, как кардиолог, и работать, как хирург. Нужна запятая?

Tags: запятые

«думать, как кардиолог, и работать, как хирург»
Нужна запятая?
Склоняюсь, что да... Думать так, как кардиолог. И работать так, как хирург... Верно? Нельзя сказать, думать по-хируржьи и работать по-кардиоложьи))))... Чтобы не ставить запятую.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129681/discussion-on-question-by-flossyu-------).

Comment: @flossyU Подстановка "по-" сомнительна и ненадёжна. Вы видите, что она вас подвела. Розенталь такое нигде не советовал.

Comment: Меня подвело «работать так, как кардиолог....»..... Если мне мерещится «так» и, соответственно, «как»....То я склоняюсь к запятой....

Comment: Но это хороший способ проверки. Просто как он может работать так, как хирург, если он и есть хирург? Этот момент необходимо учитывать.

Answer (score 4):

Без контекста ничего тут нельзя сказать наверняка. Это очевидно.
Беда-то в том, что тут и контекст вряд ли выручит.

Там в комментариях под другими ответами есть примеры в тему, но у меня есть совсем уже убийственный...
Вот, предположим, на репетиции говорит режиссер актеру, играющему роль медика:
***"Ты, Актер Драматургович, должен научиться думать как кардиолог и работать как хирург!"***

И кто решится сказать, "в роли хирурга" (т.е. в качестве) тут или "подобно хирургу"?
Я не рискну. Тот самый случай, когда обстоятельственный оборот невозможно отличить от сравнительного. Я в таких случаях не обособлял бы. Но это мое личное восприятие текста.

Решил пока этим и ограничиться. Доказывать-то особо и нечего

> Нельзя сказать, думать по-хируржьи и работать по-кардиоложьи))))... Чтобы не ставить запятую.

А вот тут надо пояснить. Это правило работает только в одну сторону, да и то с некоторыми оговорками. Если можно заменить на подобную конструкцию без изменения смысла, то это (как правило!) оборот обстоятельственный. А вот обратное ("если нельзя, то сравнительный") в корне неверно. Причин того, что "нельзя", может быть несколько (стилистические, грамматические, словарные, даже фонетические), но только одну из них: такая замена повлекла бы изменение смысла, можно признать неким критерием.

Я вот о чем. Заменим профессии на что-то более гибкое в плане образования наречий.
***Думать как рыбак, работать как дворник***,
***Думать как игрок, работать как доктор***,
***Думать как рабочий, работать как крестьянин***.
Ну понятно, что в этих фразах можно разглядеть иронические или какие-то еще смысловые акценты, коих нет в исходной. Но в общем-то обороты построены по той же схеме, но при этом допускают замену на вполне употребительные наречия "по-рыбацки", "по-игроцки", "по-рабочему", "по-крестьянски" и проч.

Так чем исходная-то конструкция хуже? Только тем, что слова "по-хируржьи" и "по-кардиоложьи" не нашли своего места в словаре?

//======

Вообще у редакторов когда-то было "золотое правило". Если совершенно непонятно, нужна ли запятая, то она нужна.
Но это, видимо, не про наш случай. Здесь, на мой вкус, запятые даже зрительно перегружают текст.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129682/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus-------).

Comment: Перенесу кое-что сюда, потому что чат со временем автомат. удаляется. Пример про актёра хорош, пытается сломать систему. Если он играет хирурга, то он всё равно не является хирургом на самом деле, хоть он и хирург на сцене (что условно). Там сравнение с таким смыслом: *работать так, как настоящий хирург работает*. То есть примерно так, ориентируясь на это, правдоподобно имитируя, потому что точь-в-точь сможет лишь настоящий хирург, знающий все нюансы. А работать хирургом можно лишь в больнице, другое дело "играть как хирург" (хирургом). Не путать с: *играть так, как настоящий хирург бы играл*.

Comment: *Я скорее пойму это как "работать хирургом"* — хирургом работает не актёр, а персонаж, актёр лишь имитирует, уподобляясь хирургу (подобно), — отчего бывают киноляпы.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не всё так чисто. Чаще запятая нужна — при сравнении (**тогда можно вставить слово "так"**). Но порой она может быть не нужна:
*Ты можешь у нас работать как хирург.* || Работать хирургом. Замена на творительный падеж, которая указана у Розенталя.
*Ты можешь думать как кардиолог, а не как дилетант?* || При изъятии оборота нарушается структура, поэтому запятая не ставится.
*Почему ты не можешь думать как кардиОлог? Ты ведь учился на него.* || Как раз что подходит "по-кардиоложьи". Подходит противопоставление: а не как кто-либо другой.

Думать, как кардиолог, редко можно без запятой, а работать как хирург (хирургом) — довольно часто.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129691/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd--------).

Answer (score 1):

**думать, как кардиолог, и работать, как хирург**

Сравнительный оборот или неполные придаточные сравнительные? Без контекста воспринимаю эти конструкции как придаточные предложения, ср.: ***Думать, как кардиолог [думает], и работать, как хирург [работает].*** Предикативность чувствуется в выделенных конструкциях.

**Поэтому запятые перед "как" нужны.**

Comment: Вот и я так думаю.... Но мои мысли здесь коллеги отвергли...